# Transition max-height on react styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, transition

So I have this code :
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-driscoll-jvvvvs?file=/src/Picker.tsx
And I am trying to create a slide-down animation on click of the Selector but it doesn't work , however if you were to add an opacity and corresponding transition for example it works perfectly fine. Some suggestions? ( tried with both height , max-height , even display none ? 0.o )

Comment: Please add relevant code to the question as link may expire in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you can't display DOM nodes and transition them in the same frame.
If you'd want to animate anything, you should render the DOM nodes first, and then trigger the animation/transition.
Or you can render the DOM nodes at all times, and then just animate them.

If edited your Example to always render the DOM elements and just trigger the animation (you can also remove the opacity transition if you want to, or delay the opacity transition by using the [transition delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay)). If you want me to elaborate more about how to remove the transition effect, leave a comment :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-cache-lb6yd9

Comment: Oh wow , with the translate is ingenious . And yeah saying it like that it makes a lot of sense . Thanks ( p.s. if had more reputation would upvote )

Comment: Hey :) sure thing, happy to help.
Since it's your question you can also mark my answer as the accepted answer. This would give me some reputation and also lets others know that your question has been answered in case someone has a similar question like this, they could find my answer easier.